# Send emptyText to Service SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uitextfield, combine

I want to send empty text inside the `searchText` to `AuthorService()` if button value `.isCancel` is true. So that my author search result will be cleaned.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct AuthorSearchBar: View {
        @StateObject var service = AuthorService()
        @Binding var isCancel: Bool
        @State var emptyText = ""
        var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
               HStack {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                if isCancel == false{
                TextField("Search", text: $service.searchText)
                } else if isCancel {
                    TextField("Search", text: $service.searchText = "") 
            //Cannot assign to property: '$service' is immutable
            //Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Binding<String>'
            //Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
                }
                .padding()
                .onReceive(Just( self.isCancel ? emptyText : service.searchText), perform: { _ in
                    service.fetchData()
                })
            }
        }
}
```

My service `fetchData()` gets searchText parameter as below.

so I want to send "" to fetchData if .isCancel is true.

```
class AuthorService: ObservableObject {
@Published var searchText : String = ""
func fetchData() {
    let parameters = ["index": "authors", "query": "\(searchText)" ]
```

Comment: Neither description nor code is clear. Would you elaborate more on details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, still not sure I understood the flow, but let's try...

Having some assumptions (mentioned in comments) the approach might be as follows (original code is not testable so answer was prepared just here - might be typos, adapting is on you, but idea should be clear):

```
struct AuthorSearchBar: View {

    @StateObject var service = AuthorService()
    @Binding var isCancel: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
           HStack {
             Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
             TextField("Search", text: $service.searchText)
                .padding()
           }
            .onReceive(Just(service.searchText)) { text in
                if !text.isEmpty {  // assuming search only for existed text
                   service.fetchData(for: text)
                }
            }
            .onReceive(Just(self.isCancel)) { canceled in
                if canceled {
                    // assuming needed to send on explicit cancel
                    service.fetchData(for: "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// pass what should be sent via argument instead of use property
func fetchData(for text: String) {
    let parameters = ["index": "authors", "query": "\(text)" ]

    ...
}
```

**Alternate:** no changes to `fetchData`, but in that case it is not possible to separate case with empty string as entered and on canceled (though it is not clear if it does matter).

```
   HStack {
     Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
     TextField("Search", text: $service.searchText)
        .padding()
   }
    .onReceive(Just(service.searchText)) { text in
        service.fetchData()
    }
    .onReceive(Just(self.isCancel)) { canceled in
        if canceled {
            service.searchText = ""  // << this activates above onReceive
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using fetchData service functions in so many other places. Most of the places I am not even looking for a text. So can there be a better way to push text inside the fetchData func?

Comment: See updated with some alternate approach... actually from two it should be clear the overall direction.